# Currency code comes with Unicode while export to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, grid

I am exporting to excel gridview. I have symbol in grid price for pound and when I do export to excel symbol comes with unicode like Price (Â£).

How can I get rid off from that symbol?

Comment: How are you exporting?Some third party dll or some custom solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
```

I have taken it from stack overflow itself

[How to export pound symbol from a C# Web App to Excel correctly? (Â£ is produced instead of £)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772016/how-to-export-pound-symbol-from-a-c-sharp-web-app-to-excel-correctly-is-pro)

Thanks