# How can export the html data to Excel using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a task to export the html data to excel using C#. I have converted the data into JSON object and how to create a excel from the Custom object.I have a custom object as Employee which has properties as Name,Address and Salary.

Can any one help me regarding this ?

Comment: Check this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598708/export-data-as-excel-file-from-asp-net?rq=1)

Comment: I have checked previously but I need to create excel using JSON serialized object.

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches that you could take.

1. You could use [Excel Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
2. You could use open [XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Personally I would go with the second approach, since it does not require MS Excel to be installed.