# Export Data to Excel without Server-side install

Tags: c#, .net

I want to export my data from grid view to the excel. Unfortunately i came to know that there is no excel software on server side. Is there any way that i can still export data in excel format without having excel software on server side.

Thanks.

Comment: Which kind of server  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a CSV format text file, which excel can understand.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150339/generating-an-excel-file-in-asp-net) also outlines some other options you might be able to use, with pros and cons of both.

Answer (score 0):

This must be one of the most asked questions on Stackoverflow.

See [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c)  For lots of suggestions and a whole list of linked questions.

Answer (score 0):

One trick you can use it to export the html table to the client with the extension of `.xls`.  When the user opens the document with Excel and resaves it will become a real excel document.  The fun part is it will retain most of the formatting from the HTML view.  This works with HTML/TABLES, I'm not sure about DIV/SPAN/CSS.