# XLS formatting with basic table?

Tags: formatting, xls

I'm trying to create a simple report on an intranet site. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150339/generating-an-excel-file-in-asp-net/150368#150368), I think I want to just go with a simple HTML table syntax. In that post, [Joel Coehoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn) says that there are some limited formatting options you can perform. Is it possible to add borders to the cells, and if so, how? My google-fu has failed to provide any results, likely because most people want a little more power at the price of simplicity. I just need simplicity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info in [this post](http://www.designdetector.com/archives/05/07/HTMLToExcelTheEasyWay.php) it looks like you can use css:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            td{
                border: thin black solid;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Hi</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>=sum(b1*2)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Now this is some long text</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>=sum(b1*b2)</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```