# vb.net generalized write of data to excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, oledb

I need to create an excel file from scratch in VB.NET given a DataTable from asp.net.
I can do this for a specific file, but I don't know how to do it for a general database.
That is, where I use the "CREATE TABLE ..." I don't know how to tell it what types to use for the data in the table.

The DataTable is derived from a FoxPro database.  (I don't know if that matters.)

I invoke the table similar to as follows:

```
<%
return_value =  make_excel( sql_table, excel_filename)
%>
```

make_excel is defined as

```
Option Explicit On 
'Option Strict On

Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.Page
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb


Public Class clsCommon
    Inherits Page

    ' buncha other stuff defined in here.

    Public Shared Function make_excel(ByVal sqlTable As DataTable, ByVal xls_fn As String) As Boolean
        Dim conn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim ds As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand()

        conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & xls_fn & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        conn.Open()

        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE MyTable ( Admin  char(20), first_name char(20));"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable ( Admin, first_name ) VALUES ('true', 'Bob')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        conn.Close()

        Return True
    End Function

End Class
```

What I need to be able to do is run through the values in sqlTable above, check their type and then build the sql to write them.  Pointers?

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that the thing doesn't like the field name "password" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to the problem.   I'm not happy about it as a general solution, but it works well enough for the cases I'm currently dealing with.

In this solution, I create a template of the excel file that has the column headings I want to use.  When I do the select in the forward code, I change the name of the fields as appropriate (or drop whatever fields I don't want).

Public Shared Function TestXL(ByVal resp As HttpResponse, ByVal sqlTable As DataTable, ByVal xls_template_fn As String, ByVal xls_fn As String) As Boolean
    Dim conn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim ds As System.Data.DataSet
    Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand()

```
Dim r As DataRow
Dim c As DataColumn
Dim i As Integer
Dim sql As String
dim str as string

If File.Exists(xls_template_fn) Then
    try 
      If File.Exists(xls_fn) Then
        File.Delete(xls_fn)
      Else
        File.Copy(xls_template_fn, xls_fn)
      End If
    catch ex1 as Exception
      File.Copy(xls_template_fn, xls_fn)
    End Try
Else
    resp.Write("Unable to locate template file: " & xls_template_fn)
    Return False
End If

conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & xls_fn & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
conn.Open()


cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandText = sql


For Each r In sqlTable.Rows
    sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable ("
    For i = 0 To sqlTable.Columns.Count - 1
        sql = sql & " " & sqlTable.Columns(i).ColumnName & ","
    Next
    sql = Left(sql, sql.Length - 1) & " ) VALUES ( "
    For i = 0 To sqlTable.Columns.Count - 1
    str = r(i).toString()
        dim str2 as string = str.replace("'", "''")
        sql = sql & " '" & str2 & "',"
    Next
    sql = Left(sql, sql.Length - 1) & " );"


    'resp.Write(sql & "<br/>")

    cmd.CommandText = sql
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next

conn.Close()

Return True
```

End Function

Note the name of the the worksheet is the name of the table for the oledb call.

There's a link to other ways of doing this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erikaehrli/archive/2009/01/30/how-to-export-data-to-excel-from-an-asp-net-application-avoid-the-file-format-differ-prompt.aspx

If I have to revisit this problem I'll probably start there.

Comment: I notice this problem was already addressed - not sure how I missed it - in another Stackoverflow thread at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150339/generating-an-excel-file-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the copyfromrecordset function? You'll need to do a bit of work and its a bit of a change of approach but it might be something you can look into. An MS article is available [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246335) (Sorry, the article is based around VBA, but it should help as a guide).

Comment: Thanks for note.  I started out trying to use ADO, as I've done similar before with VBA; however, I couldn't figure out what IMPORTS to use to get the methods and so have gone down this other route.  That particular method is unfamiliar to me, though - so thanks for that.