# Create Excel workbook in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vsto, ms-office

I need to generate an excel file for a user on the fl upon button click. I was using [Netoffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) before which worked fine for desktop applications. 
But now I want to do the same thing with an asp.net app. This way my server code doesn't have an access to the client's copy of excel. What approach should I take?

Comment: Looks a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150339/generating-an-excel-file-in-asp-net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). It allows you to create Excel spreadsheets on the server. I've used it and it worked great. It supports advanced functions.

```
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
    //Create the worksheet
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");

    //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true);

    //Format the header for column 1-3
    using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:C1"])
    {
        rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;

        //Set Pattern for the background to Solid
        rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(79, 129, 189));

        //Set color to dark blue
        rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
    }

    //Example how to Format Column 1 as numeric 
    using (ExcelRange col = ws.Cells[2, 1, 2 + tbl.Rows.Count, 1])
    {
        col.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00";
        col.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;
    }

    //Write it back to the client
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=file.xlsx");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";                    
    Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Looks cool. Though I cannot find an example on how to create a workbook and download it to the client without saving to the server? Do you know an easy way of doing that?

Comment: I added some code which shows creating a workbook with a spreadsheet and writing it to the client.

Comment: Should EPPlus be downloaded as Dll and linked to reference of my project? I would like to use it...

Answer (score 3):

The most flexible and likely to do exactly what you need is going to take some work, but it's free -- and really works.  Use the toolkit to look at existing documents to see how to create the features you want.

[Open XML 2.0 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124)

Answer (score 0):

You can try simple HTML table (inlcude html, head, and body tags).
Just save it with XLS extension.

---

[image]

Comment: No, I need some complex excel manipulation. netoffice would work great, but I do not understand why it cannot work with asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Netoffice requires MS Office on executing machine. Does your server has it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DataGrid to create Excel files on the fly. It doesn't require Excel.

```
public static void ExportDataSetToExcel(DataSet ds, string filename)
{
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

    // first let's clean up the response.object
    response.Clear();
    response.Charset = "";

    // set the response mime type for excel
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    response.AddHeader(
        "Content-Disposition",
        "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\""
    );

   // create a string writer
   using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
   {
       using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
       {
            // instantiate a datagrid
            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
            dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dg.DataBind();
            dg.RenderControl(htw);
            response.Write(sw.ToString());
            dg.Dispose();
            ds.Dispose();
            response.End();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution returns **HTML** to the client, but declares that it is actually an **Excel** file. The problem with that is that Excel is on to your little deception, and throws a warning dialog at the user explaining that someone's trying to lie to them.