# How to generate and send to client Excel report in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am new to the whole issue of generating/sending Excel report in ASP.net.

The Code below sometimes does not work for large amount of data (large Excel report), but only if user, located not in our company, requests it from his browser. It always works if I run it, and I am located in the same building where server is.

Client has IE9 and MS Office 2010. Client does not get any errors. Client simply does not get report after long wait time. Seems to timeout without errors.

Are there any alternative to the approach below, for providing client with large Excel report ?

Anything done wrong in the code below that may cause the problem?

What is the best=robust way to generate report for the client that can be opened on the client side in Excel ?

```
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel" 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + ReportName + ".xls") 

Response.Write("<table border =1>") 
For Each ch As ColumnHeaders In arrCh 
    If ch.ColumnName <> "" Then 
            pCh = pCh & "<td><b>" & ch.ColumnName & "</b></td>" 
                    pColCount = pColCount + 1 
                End If 
Next 

If pExtraHeader <> "" Then 
    Response.Write(pExtraHeader) 
End If 
Response.Write("<tr>" & pCh & "</tr>") 
If oSQLDataReader.HasRows Then 
    Do While oSQLDataReader.Read() 
            Response.Write("<tr>") 
                For I = 0 To arrCh.Count - 1 
                    If arrCh(I + 1).columnname <> "" Then 
                        Response.Write("<td>" & strColumnValue & "</td>") 
                        If arrCh.Item(I + 1).isTotal = True Then 
                            arrCh.Item(I + 1).placeholder = CDbl(arrCh.Item(I + 1).placeholder) + CDbl(oSQLDataReader.GetValue(I)) 
                        End If 
                     End If 
                Next 
                Response.Write("</tr>") 
        Loop 

        Dim pTotal As String = "" 
        For Each ch As ColumnHeaders In arrCh 
            If ch.ColumnName <> "" Then 
              pTotal = pTotal & "<td><b>" & strColumnValue & "</b></td>" 
          End If 
        Next 
    Response.Write("<tr>" & pTotal & "</tr>" 

End If 
Response.Write("</table>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that all the code? Are you flushing the response and finalizing it?

Other than that, in the case of excel there are lots of server components to automatically generate an excel workbook and return the file as an attachment to the client (all processing is done on the server).

And lastly (and this is always a last resort measure) you have Excel Automation on the server.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150339/generating-an-excel-file-in-asp-net?rq=1), here's a breakdown of the different alternatives you have available.

Comment: Response.End() is used after Response.Write().

Comment: I did not write this code and it looks like Response.End() should not be used after all. It looks like context.Response.Flush();
context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();  should be used after Response.Write() in non-error case. Do you agree ?

Comment: Yes, response.end is to be avoided