# How to make a browse window for selecting destination when button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I have a simple button for exporting a database table from MySQL to excel file. So far its destination is hardcoded to C:/ drive. When you press the Export button you get excel file automatically exported to C: without the user able to see it.
Here is the code:

```
//button for Exporting to Excel (.xls)
    //hardcoded destination to C:/
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = "server=localhost; UserId=root; database=dbcss; ";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

            con.Open();
            string getProject = ddlProjectID.SelectedValue; //get the already selected project from the dropdown menu

            //create sql command object
            string cmdText = "SELECT 'activity_id', 'activity_name', 'wbs_no', 'activity_status', 'wbs_name', 'sequence', 'pad', 'project_id', 'start_date', 'finish_date' INTO OUTFILE 'C://TASK.xls' FROM management WHERE project_id = '" + getProject + "';";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

How can I make a window pop-up where you can browse your pc and select destination?

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your response header and content type and send back a file to the browser:

Try these:

[Send query results to Excel from ASP.NET website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148945/send-query-results-to-excel-from-asp-net-website)

[One click ASP.NET export button control for Excel/CSV file](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/Excel_CSV_export_button.aspx)

Comment: I think both of the examples (at least the first one) are exporting the gridview not the raw database table. Am I right?
And for me the grid view is different thing compared to the database because its a set of views...
I don't know about the second example because VB is not familiar to me.